# How can I add a switch layout to a RecyclerView from a different activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I try to add a new card view to the recycler view by sending an intent from a different activity. 
The recycler view element category_switch_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".NotificationManager">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/notificationCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/yourNotificationsLayout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notificationSwitchText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:hint="Switch"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/notificationSwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I send the intent from NewNotification.java:

```
createNotifButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationManager.class);
                i.putExtra("notifName",categoryInput.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

I get the intent in NotificationManager.java:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String newNotifName = intent.getStringExtra("notifName");
        addToNotificationList(newNotifName);
```

addToNotificationList function:

```
private void addToNotificationList(String newNotifName) {
        this.notificationList.add(new Notification(newNotifName,false));

    }
```

Finally, here is the Adapter class that I populate the RecyclerView:

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater linflater;
    private ArrayList<Notification> notifList;

    public NotificationAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Notification> notifList) {
        linflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.notifList = notifList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = linflater.inflate(R.layout.category_switch_row,parent,false);
        return new NotificationViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotificationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.notificationText.setText(notifList.get(position).getName());
        holder.notificationSwitch.setChecked(notifList.get(position).isSwitched());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notifList.size();
    }

    public class NotificationViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView notificationText;
        Switch notificationSwitch;

        public NotificationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            notificationText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notificationSwitchText);
            notificationSwitch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notificationSwitch);

        }
    }
}
```

However, even before I add the notification by the category input, from the NewNotification class, the layout displays a Switch without a text and adds the text after sending the Intent. What I want is creating the text and the switch only after the addition, meaning after the intent is sent. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a null check here:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String newNotifName = intent.getStringExtra("notifName");
if(newNotifName != null){
    addToNotificationList(newNotifName);
}
```

Without the null check, you always try to get the extra for "notifName" and you call `addToNotificationList` even when no value has been passed to your activity. This will add an item to your `RecyclerCiew` without a text, which leads to the creation of a `CardView` where the `TextView` has no text.

Comment: Yep, I thought the problem was calling the function in the onCreate function. However, adding a null check solved my problem. Thank you.